# C# functions with multiple fat arrows

Tags: c#

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this function with multiple fat arrows.

```
services.AddTransient<ServiceA>();
services.AddTransient<ServiceB>();
services.AddTransient<ServiceC>();

services.AddTransient<ServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "A":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceA>();
        case "B":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceB>();
        case "C":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceC>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(); // or maybe return null, up to you
    }
});
```

In C# i have never come across this function style serviceProvider => key =>.
Can anyone please explain to me what it means

Comment: It's a new [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions)

Comment: Looks like a lambda function that returns another lambda.

Comment: JS answer, same advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323357/1043380

Comment: @Aarnihauta no, it is not)

Comment: usual nested lambda functions, _not_ the C# 8 switch expression

Comment: I am familiar with JS and in JS its called Higher Order Function. But i am not familiar with this in c#

Comment: This is a good example of how people are using lambda's -that were added to make the language more expressive- in a complex, not expressive way. But I guess that's [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/)

Comment: @jhon.smith It's still a higher order function - the name is not JS specific

Comment: `=>` is commonly read as "goes to".  See [How do I pronounce "=>" as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274022/150605) and [C# Lambda ( => )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3970219/150605)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, it is a high-order function, so it's a function which returns another function.

Let's see the last `AddTransient` method call's parameter from inside out:

```
key =>
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "A":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceA>();
        case "B":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceB>();
        case "C":
            return serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceC>();
        default:
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(); // or maybe return null, up to you
    }
};
```

You can describe this function as a `Func<String, Object>` if `ServiceA` ... `ServiceC` don't have any common ancestor / does not implement a common interface.

So you have a function which receives a string (`key`) and returns an `object`.

---

```
serviceProvider => key =>
{
    ...
}
```

This function can be described with `Func<ServiceProvider, Func<String, Object>>`. If this function receives a `serviceProvider` instance during its method call then it will return a function which anticipates a string and returns an object.

If you have a function like the above then you can call the inner via the outer:

```
Func<ServiceProvider, Func<String, Object>> factoryMethodRegister = ...
Func<String, Object> factoryMethod = factoryMethodRegister(sp);
Object instance = factoryMethod(key);

//OR
Func<ServiceProvider, Func<String, Object>> factoryMethodRegister = ...
Object instance = factoryMethodRegister(sp)(key);
```

Comment: wow Amazing break down of the subject and excellent explanation thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) returning another lambda expression.

Not sure what is `ServiceResolver` but I would say that it is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) looking something like this:

```cs
// IService - shared contract for ServiceA, ServiceB, ...
public delegate IService ServiceResolver(string key);
```

Then the invocation `services.AddTransient<ServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => ...)` is a call to [`AddTransient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addtransient-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-1)))) method accepting a [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) delegate, which is constructed via [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) and returning another delegate constructed also via lambda expression (`key => {...}`).

Comment: Yup, this is it exactly. though I would guess instead of `object` it is an interface that ServiceA, B and C implement.

Comment: @DavidG yes, that what I was trying to reflect in the comment.